# pandas grouping and visualization

Tags: python, pandas

I have to do some analysis using Python3 and pandas with a dataset which is shown as a toy example-

```
data
'''
    location importance    agent  count
0     London        Low  chatbot      2
1        NYC     Medium  chatbot      1
2     London       High    human      3
3     London        Low    human      4
4        NYC       High    human      1
5        NYC     Medium  chatbot      2
6  Melbourne        Low  chatbot      3
7  Melbourne        Low    human      4
8  Melbourne       High    human      5
9        NYC       High  chatbot      5
'''
```

My aim is to group the location and then count the number of Low, Medium and/or High 'importance' column for each location. So far, the code I have come up with is-

```
data.groupby(['location', 'importance']).aggregate(np.size)
'''
                      agent  count
location  importance              
London    High            1      1
          Low             2      2
Melbourne High            1      1
          Low             2      2
NYC       High            2      2
          Medium          2      2
'''
```

This grouping and count aggregation contains index as the grouping objects-

```
data.groupby(['location', 'importance']).aggregate(np.size).index
```

I don't know how to proceed next? Also, how can I visualize this?

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), added `aggfunc=sum` for aggregate if duplicates and then use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df = data.pivot_table(index='location', columns='importance', values='count', aggfunc='sum')

df.plot()
```

If need counts of pairs `location` with `importance` use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(data['location'], data['importance'])

df.plot()
```

Comment: 'count' and 'agent' columns are inconsequential, hence can be removed from 'pivot_table()' ?

Comment: @Arun - Not understand, what mean `inconsequential` ?

Comment: it means that the rest of the columns/attributes like 'agent' and 'count' do not matter.

Comment: @Arun - So need second solution?

Comment: @Arun - Sorry, I am confused, what is necessary ploting? Second solution is for counts for `location` vs `importance`.

Comment: second solution is fine for visualization